# Telerik Reporting - can't export in Chrome when using SqlDataSource

Tags: google-chrome, telerik, telerik-reporting, export-to-pdf

EDIT 2: Using fiddler I was able to find out that I'm getting a 504 error, but it makes no sense to me how that could possibly be happening.

EDIT: It seems to have something to do with connecting to SQL Server. I found I can export reports that don't use a SqlDataSource just fine, but when I add one then I get this error. But I still have no idea how to debug beyond this.

---

My Telerik reports are exporting just fine in explorer, but in Chrome I am getting an error page that says "This webpage is not available" and below that it says "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET".

When I hit F12 and look at the network activity, this is the request that is causing the problem:

https://ourwebsite.com/api/reportresolver/clients/112517-7243/instances/112518-d54c/documents/112531-33fe?response-content-disposition=attachment

The odd thing is that I can take the above link and copy/paste it into Explorer and it will open the PDF I just tried to export from Chrome.

Has anyone else run into this? I have no idea how to even proceed in troubleshooting this further :/

Comment: Clear your cookies and try again.

Comment: @Roshith Thanks, but unfortunately the problem isn't isolated to my pc. It happens the same for everyone else in the office and for our customers.

Comment: Also I tried it in FireFox and got a similar error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I export to PDF programmatically using the sample code provided by Telerik (http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/reporting/styling-and-formatting-reports/details/exporting-a-report-to-pdf-programmatically) I get similar results. However if I remove Response.End() then it works great.

The odd thing is that it works properly in test projects the way it's supposed to from the toolbar; it's only when it's integrated into the application I need to use it in that I have to export it programmatically (without Response.End()) in order to get it to work in browsers other than IE.

Still wish I could figure out how to get it to work from the toolbar, but at this point I don't expect any answers so this will have to do :/

EDIT: I later found that the amount of data being passed had something to do with it. If there was very little data being passed then it worked okay but as soon as the amount of data increased a little then the above solution of removing Response.End() was required.